# Let $\phi \in [0,1]^X$ integrable, $A\subseteq B$, and $\phi (X\setminus A)=\{0\}$, is $\frac{\mathbb{E}(\phi |B)}{\mathbb{E}(\phi |A)}=1?$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

I have a conceptual problem with the relation between two integrable functions that are equal a.e.. Here there is a possible setting, to make things more concrete.

> **Question:**
>
> *Assumptions:*
>
> - $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ is a measure space,
> - $A, B \in \Sigma$, with $A \subseteq B$,
> - $\phi \in [0,1]^X$ is a measurable (and integrable) function, with $\phi (X \setminus A) = \{ 0 \}$.
>
> If we focus on the ***conditional expectation*** of $\mu$, defined for an arbitrary $Y \in \Sigma$ as 
>   $$ \mathbb{E} \ (\ \phi \ | \ Y ) := \frac{1}{\mu (Y)} \int_Y \phi d \mu, $$
>   can we state – *given the previously described setting* – that the following is true:
>   $$ \frac{\mathbb{E} \ (\ \phi \ | \ B ) }{\mathbb{E} \ (\ \phi \ | \ A )}= 1 ?$$

To me this make sense, because essentially the two expectations are the same, given the condition $\phi (X \setminus A)$. Still I am not completely sure.

Is the line of reasoning sound?
Is actually correct to talk about equality a.e. in this kind of context?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: To conclude that $$ \frac{\mathbb{E} \ (\ \phi \ | \ B ) }{\mathbb{E} \ (\ \phi \ | \ A )}= 1 $$  we need that $\mu(B \setminus A) = 0 $.   The condition $\phi (X \setminus A) = \{ 0 \}$ is not enough. In fact, if you only know that  $\phi (X \setminus A) = \{ 0 \}$, then you can only conclude

$$ \frac{\mathbb{E} \ (\ \phi \ | \ B ) }{\mathbb{E} \ (\ \phi \ | \ A )}= \frac{\mu(A)}{\mu(B)} $$

But you cannot conclude that $\mu(A)=\mu(B)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Superuseful comment! Now, going a step further, your last formula then basically implies $$\displaystyle \frac{\mathbb{E} ( \phi | B)}{\mathbb{E}(\phi | A)} = \mu(A |B),$$ because given the assumptions, $\mu (A | B) = \frac{\mu (A)}{\mu(B)}$. Am I actually right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: @Ramiro: after quite some time I went back to this question and I have troubles seeing your answer. I don't see why – given all the assumptions – we need additionally that $\mu ( B \setminus A ) = 0$ to conclude that $$\frac{\mathbb{E} (\phi | B)}{\mathbb{E} (\phi | A)} = 1.$$ Could you please expand on this in an answer? I will be really happy to vote and accept it.

Comment: Ok. I have expanded the details in an answer. Please, let me know if you have any question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Assumptions:*
>
> - $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ is a measure space,
> - $A, B \in \Sigma$, with $A \subseteq B$,
> - $\phi \in [0,1]^X$ is a measurable (and integrable) function, with $\phi (X \setminus A) = \{ 0 \}$.

So we have:

$$ \int_B \phi d \mu = \int_{B \setminus A} \phi d \mu + \int_A \phi d \mu= \int_A \phi d \mu$$

because $B \setminus A \subseteq X \setminus A $ and $\phi (X \setminus A) = \{ 0 \}$, so $\phi (B \setminus A) = \{ 0 \}$.

So we have

$$ \int_B \phi d \mu = \int_A \phi d \mu = c$$

for some  $c \in \mathbb{R} $.

Then, assuming $\mu(A) \neq 0$ we have that $\mu(B) \neq 0$, and we have:

$$ \mathbb{E} \ (\ \phi \ | \ B ) := \frac{1}{\mu (B)} \int_B \phi d \mu = \frac{c}{\mu (B)} $$
and 
$$ \mathbb{E} \ (\ \phi \ | \ A ) := \frac{1}{\mu (A)} \int_A \phi d \mu = \frac{c}{\mu (A)} $$

Assuming that $\phi$ is NOT null a.e., we have that $c \neq 0$. Assuming $\mu(A)$ is finite, we have $\mathbb{E} \ (\ \phi \ | \ A ) \neq 0$. So we have:

$$ \frac{\mathbb{E} \ (\ \phi \ | \ B )}{\mathbb{E} \ (\ \phi \ | \ A )} = \frac{\mu (A)}{\mu (B)}$$

**Remark:** We can conclude that

$$ \frac{\mathbb{E} \ (\ \phi \ | \ B )}{\mathbb{E} \ (\ \phi \ | \ A )} = 1$$

if and only if

$$ \mu (A) = \mu (B)$$

Since $A \subseteq B$ and $\mu(A)$ is finite, the last condition is equivalent to $\mu(B \setminus A) =0$.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions do not happen in useful situations. Apply your hypothesis to $A=\emptyset$ and $B=X.$ The $\phi$ must be zero on the complement of $A,$ i.e., everywhere.

Now if these conditions apply only for *a particular choice* of $A$ and $B$ then I have to argue that $E[\phi|A]$ is different from $E[\phi|B]$ as soon as one of these two numbers is nonzero and $\mu(B-A)>0$ (so that $\mu(A)\neq\mu(B)$).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Still, if we do not focus on extreme situations, beyond the usefulness of the conditions, does my statement make sense (again, assuming $A\neq \varnothing$, and $B \neq X$)? As a self-thaught I am never really confident, and I was wondering about it.

Comment: I would have understood the question more easily if "arbitrary" had been replaced with "certain".

Comment: Yep you are right. I actually wrote "arbitrary", in the sense that we fix it once and for all, and then we work with them.